# Remember Snow Leopard Firewall settings

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard

I've got the firewall enabled on my Snow Leopard installation, and it works just fine, except for with EyeTV.  Every time I run this app, a popup appears asking if I want to allow it access to the network, even though I've got it added in the application list for allowed apps.  Any ideas how I can stop this from asking and just let it be given access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow all of these steps?

http://support.elgato.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=3651

Comment: Thanks, I'd gone through all those steps, but I just updated to a new version and it appears to have resolved the issue.  Cheers!